# OpenCV "real world" coordinates / measurements from stereo camera

Tags: opencv, camera-calibration, emgucv, stereo-3d

I have two cameras mounted on some rig.

I want to get "real world" coordinates in millimeters of some object which center is at (x1, y1) on the left image and (x2, y2) on the right image.

What I've done so far:

1. Printed out some chessboard image.
2. Detected corners of chessboard using `FindChessboardCorners` on ~20 frames with me holding chessboard in different angle and position.
3. Using results from `FindChessboardCorners` I calibrated my stereo camera using `StereoCalibrate` function.
4. Computed rectification transforms using `StereoRectify` function.
5. Using results from `StereoCalibrate` and `StereoRectify` I called `InitUndistortRectifyMap` to get maps for left and right cameras.
6. Remapped my original frames with `Remap` function using outputs from `InitUndistortRectifyMap`.

What would be my next steps do actual calculation of real-world coordinates?

Matas